# Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk equivalent on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, monitoring

Sorry for yet another NUBISH question..

I need to gather perf data from the local system 'disk latency' etc..

Google keeps giving me CLI tools, but I need to access the C++ structs..

Any ideas??

Also if anyone knows of a good reference about extracting OS details in C++ then I can read it before asking such nubish questions..

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ language will never deal with OS details, it is up to OS to provide its tools and APIs for that (if any), and so there are no support for that in C++ language. On Linux there are files that contain such statistics.

- **/proc/stat** contains system statistics.
- **/proc/partitions** contains disk statistics.
- **/proc/diskstats** contains disks statistics.
- **/sys** contains statistics for block devices.

If you have no idea how to deal with those files then perhaps take source code of [iostat](http://linuxinsight.com/iostat_utility.html) utility of Linux and see yourself. There are more utilities (like iotop, dstat, atop, ioping) if iostat isn't doing what you need.

Comment: /sys/block/<dev>/stat
Was the soft spot ;)  Thanks Öö Tiib